# Getting 504 Gateway Timeout Error if I upload any large documents in Azure using the below python code in Azure Web App

Tags: python, azure

Please have a look into this and let me know how to fix this.

If I upload any large document for validation, it is taking more than 4 mins and getting time out error in azure.

But I upload any small document, I am not getting any timeout error.

Thanks in advance.

```
def check_desc_errors(context, doc_type):
        desc_error_list = []
        desc_errors = []
        completelist = []
        corrections_list = []
        system_shall_have_list = []
        original_but_incorrect_list = []
        with open("media/" + doc_type + "/" + name + '.csv', 'r',encoding='utf-8') as file:
            csv_file_reader = csv.reader(file)
            list1 = []
            list2 = []
            for row in csv_file_reader:
                temp_id = row[0]
                temp = row[1]
                root = 'The system shall'
                # ignore if the cell contains N/A or end of table
                if temp == "end of table":
                    continue
                # check if the desc starts with the root
                elif not (temp.startswith(root)):
                    if doc_type == 'urs' or doc_type == 'frs':
                        system_shall_have_list.append("Description must start with \'The system shall\'")
                        desc_error_list.append((temp_id, temp))
                        desc_errors.append(temp)
                else:
                    system_shall_have_list.append("*Format OK*")
```

check grammar using GingerIt

```
# text = temp # parser = GingerIt() # result = parser.parse(text) # temporary = [] # # If there is grammatical error # if text != result['result']: # for x in result['corrections']: # y = x['text'] + '-->' + x['correct'] # temporary.append(y) # completelist.append(result['result']) # list1.append(result['result']) # list2.append((temp_id, temp)) # original_but_incorrect_list.append(temp) # else: # temporary.append('*No Correction*') # completelist.append('*No Correction*') # corrections_list.append(temporary)
                    temporary = []
                matches = tool.check(temp)
                if(len(matches)==0):
                    temporary.append('*No spell/grammar correction*')
                    completelist.append('*No spell/grammar correction*')
                else:
                    for i in range(len(matches)):
                        y = ''.join(matches[i].msg) + '-->' + ','.join(matches[i].replacements)
                        temporary.append(y)
                    z = language_check.correct(temp,matches)
                    completelist.append(z)
                    list1.append(z)
                    list2.append((temp_id, temp))
                    original_but_incorrect_list.append(temp)
    
                corrections_list.append(temporary)
    
            correction_list = zip(list1, list2)
            temp_list = zip(list2, list1)
            # write sugggested changes to a new csv file
            with open("media/" + doc_type + "/" + name + 'updated.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f_out:
                writer = csv.writer(f_out)
                writer.writerow(['Source Statement', 'Suggested Statement'])
                writer.writerows(temp_list)
    
        context['correction_list'] = correction_list
        context['len_correction_list'] = len(list1)
        context['len_desc_error_list'] = len(desc_error_list)
        context['desc_error_list'] = desc_error_list
    
        # Add corrections to excel file
        df = pd.read_excel("media/" + doc_type + "/" + name + '.xlsx', na_filter=False)  # Read Excel file as a DataFrame
        if doc_type=='urs' or doc_type=='frs':
            df['Format error - \'The system shall missing\''] = system_shall_have_list
        df['Suggested Req. Desc. based on Grammar and Spell check'] = completelist
        df['Grammar and Spell Corrections'] = corrections_list
        df.to_excel("media/" + doc_type + "/" + name + '.xlsx', index=None)
    
        fs = FileSystemStorage(location="media/" + doc_type + "/", base_url="/media/" + doc_type + "/")
        context['report_url'] = fs.url(name + 'updated.csv')
        return desc_errors, original_but_incorrect_list
```

Comment: 504 Gateway timeout is too general to know what is going wrong in backend. Do you have any error logs? There can be many reasons behind 504. Please enable diagnostic logging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs and share the logs.

Comment: Actuaaly it is due to languge-check package taking more time and occupying 100% CPU time.

Comment: Kindly advice what can be done

Comment: Are you sure gingerit consuming cpu? The reason I am asking it calls service api, so not sure why it would consume cpu at client side..did you do [profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/debug.html) your app to see?

Comment: Not gingerit........ "LanguageTool" consuming 100% CPU

Comment: What Azure service are you using and what is the tier/scale? The reason I am asking LanguageTool might have a CPU intensive demand indeed. Also can you post the pypi link of the LanguageTool  package?